# Registry or $_ENV

Tags: php, design-patterns, global

What is the difference between **Registry pattern** and **$_ENV**, especially for using in php?

Which of them provide more security and performance?

For example why many coders use **$config['deflang']** and Registry pattern instead of just **$_ENV['deflang']**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_ENV` has a very specific purpose -- it's the process environment. You're not really supposed to throw random data into it. If you want to do that, at least use a global (or, better, a static class member).

Comment: why global is better $_ENV? As I read here http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.

Comment: `$GLOBALS` is also a superglobal, and unlike `$_ENV` it doesn't have any predefined meaning. Storing arbitrary junk in `$_ENV` doesn't make any more sense than throwing it into, say, `$_GET` or `$_SERVER` would -- all of those are meant for something else.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand that $GLOBAL is more usefull than $_ENV, but what about $GLOBAL and Registry pattern? I dont need explain, just which of them provide more performance and security (of course if they provide).

Answer (score 0):

Those two things are completely different.

- `$_ENV` is a superglobal array containing all environment variables.
- `$config` is some user-defined variable, could be from a config file, a database, etc.

A common way (especially in some frameworks) is to have a config file that contains an array with multiple configs and one environment variable (e.g. `FRAMEWORKNAME_ENV`) which then selects the active config.

Comment: Thanks, but why use config file if I can use $_ENV ? Why I cant use $_ENV['db'] instead of $config['db'] ? Why its "bad"?

Comment: Because then you'd have to create environment variables for all your config vars - at least if you don't want to abuse that array by adding values to it manually.

Comment: OK then your advice is for example define $config[] with some user-defined variable and then one $_ENV['FRAMEWORKNAME_ENV'] which contain $config Array. Right?

Comment: No. Your array would be `$config = array('dev' => array(...), 'prod' => array(...))` and you'd use `$config[$_ENV['WHATEVER_ENV']][...]` and use e.g. SetEnv in your vhost config to set the env variable to `dev` or `prod` depending on which config you want.

Answer (score 0):

Registry pattern allows you to lazy-load resources.

```
$db = $_ENV['db_connection']; // The connection must be setup prior
```

vs

```
$db = $config->get('db_connection');
// An internal method can check for an existing connection 
// and set one up if needed
```

Comment: I can check connection also in function, my question about static variables which is available in all scopes throughout a script

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Registry {

    public static $instance;

    public function set($key, $val) {
        $this->_reg[$key] = $val;
    }
    public function get($key) {
        return $this->_reg[$key];
    }
    public static function Singleton() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        if (!(self::$instance instanceof $class)) {
            try {
                if (!defined('REQUIRED')) {
                    throw new Registry_Exception('No direct access.');
                }
            } catch (Registry_Exception $e) {}
            self::$instance = new $class();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    private function __construct() {}

}

$registry = new Registry();
$registry->set('setting', 'value');
```